# How to test php-fpm configuration (PHP7.0)

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, php7

I am running a webserver with Ubuntu 16 and `php-fpm` to process PHP requests. `php-fpm` has been installed via `apt-get` from the default Ubuntu repositories.

According to [this reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/php-fpm7.0.8.html) I should be able to run `php-fpm -t` to test the configuration. However, this only tells me, the there is no `php-fpm`. I quite sure, it is (the webserver incl. PHP processing works well, and the service php7.0-fpm is up and running) ... but no executable with the name `php-fpm`.

How can I test a `php-fpm` configuration change with PHP 7 before reloading the configuration?

Answer (score 12):

To test the configuration file of PHP FPM (PHP 7.0), run:

`sudo php-fpm7.0 -t`

Note that the command name could be somewhat confusing, since the systemd service is named `php7.0-fpm`.

If everything is OK, this is an example output:

```
[20-Jun-2022 21:50:07] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find php-fpm file in your system and execute the command at absolute path :
find / -type f -iname "*php-fpm*"

Comment: Usually yes, but this does not find anything on my server, except a monit configuration file :(